# Java input from the user and output as a list at the end

Tags: java

I have a task to take the input from the user(not specific number of times) and eventually output all of those inputs as a list at the very end. Inputs are integers, and this needs to be done without using the for loop.
I tried to do it myself, however I find a problem in displaying all of the values at once at the end. Since each time the user inputs the value, it overwrites it. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class dispay
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
 {
   Scanner stdIn=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please enter the ammount or '-1' to exit:");
   String input=stdIn.nextLine(); 
   int inputInt=0;  
      while(!(input.equals("-1")))
      {
      inputInt=Integer.parseInt(input);          
      System.out.print("Please enter the ammount or '-1' to exit:");
      input=stdIn.nextLine();
      }
      System.out.println("Original price: "+inputInt);
 }
}
```

Comment: show me your code sample

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Until you post your code sample, we won't be able to suggest you anything. BTW how are you taking input from user ?

Comment: I suggest you to read about `Arrays`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Specially search for `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: I am supposed to do it without any arrays...

Comment: Then use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or create your own class to save the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I would see to do this would be to use Vectors. This is not like arrays where you need a defined size in order to proceed. Vectors can grow and shrink. See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html] for more details. Basing this off the code you have already given I would recommend the following:

```
import java.util.*; /*edited this line*/
class dispay
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
  Scanner stdIn=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter the ammount or '-1' to exit:");
  String input=stdIn.nextLine(); 
  int inputInt=0;  
  Vector v=new Vector(1,1); /*defines an empty vector of ints*/
    while(!(input.equals("-1")))
    {
      inputInt=Integer.parseInt(input);
      v.addElement(new Integer(inputInt));  /*adds the new integer to the vector of ints*/         
      System.out.print("Please enter the ammount or '-1' to exit:");
      input=stdIn.nextLine();
    }
  System.out.println("Original price: "+v.toString()); /*prints the full vector in string representation*/
  }
}
```

Alternatively instead of 'v.toString()' one can use something like the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size()-1; ++i){
  System.out.print(v.get(i) + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*; /*edited this line*/
class dispay
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
  Scanner stdIn=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter the ammount or '-1' to exit:");
  String input=stdIn.nextLine(); 
  int inputInt=0;  
  Vector v=new Vector(1,1); /*defines an empty vector of ints*/
    while(!(input.equals("-1")))
    {
      inputInt=Integer.parseInt(input);
      v.addElement(new Integer(inputInt));  /*adds the new integer to the vector     of ints*/         
      System.out.print("Please enter the ammount or '-1' to exit:");
      input=stdIn.nextLine();
    }
  System.out.println("Original price: "+v.toString()); /*prints the full vector     in string representation*/
  }
}
```

Alternatively instead of 'v.toString()' one can use something like the     following:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size()-1; ++i){
  System.out.print(v.get(i) + " ");
}
```

Thanks your this worked just as I hoped it would.

Comment: Do the man a solid and upvote his answer and click the check mark beside his so you select it as the answer to your question and he gets the credit that he deserves. It is what keeps this lovely ecosystem we know as Stackoverflow running.